# How to create these kinds of graphics in Illustrator? Do they have a technical name?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm just wondering how these kinds of graphics are created, i.e. the white lines that twist and turn across the page. I see them all the time and was just wondering if there is a way to create them in Illustrator using the Blend tool or wrapping a grid along a path? I'm not sure. Thanks!

[image: Pic]

Comment: Don't let "photoshop" in the duplicate question throw you... the lines are all created in Illustrator and that question shows you how.

Comment: Thank you – yes, thats what I was looking for. I knew it was probably as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve these graphics by creating two separate wavy paths with a white stroke. Then double clicking on this guy (the blend tool) [image: Blend Tool] use the drop down menu to select "Specified Steps" and  put in however many more wavy paths you want in between the two original paths. Play around with the curve of the paths and their start and endpoints to get the effect you want.

If you're a visual learner this is a good tutorial for this effect.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2rD-36bc48

Comment: Thank you – I was pretty sure it was done with blends but I'm still relatively new to how blends work so it's still baffling that super complex looking artwork can be made so easy.